# Invalid Hook call when using useState, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have little issue I face the first time. I'm trying to use a simple useState but for some reason I can't understand why React throws me back an error and whatever I'm trying to do-nothing fix it.

[image]

that's the image of the error:
error description:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

my code:(very simple)

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

function Login() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});


  return <div> why error? </div>;
}
export default Login;
```

Tried following their solution with no luck of succeeding... thanks

EDIT: this is where I render the component -

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact render={Home} />
          <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
          <Route path="/login" exact render={Login} />
          <Route path="/register" exact render={Register} />
          <Route render={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
...
```

Comment: Maybe this link can help : https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: Where are you actually rendering the component?

Comment: tried it.. didn't help

Comment: I tried to reproduce and i dont get your error. it works for me

Comment: Check Colins answer, I tried what he says and could reproduce your error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue here is how you're rendering your component. You can't do:

```
Login()
```

but you can do:

```
<Login />
```

Update: similarly, you can't do:

```
<Route path="/login" exact render={Login} />
```

you need:

```
<Route path="/login" exact render={() => <Login />} />
```

Comment: could you please explain why? @Colin Ricardo

Comment: It's the same logic as above. If you want to render the component and not just call the functional component that's how you need to do it.

Comment: or use `component={Login}` since you don't need to use `render` there right now.

Comment: Yep, as @devserkan says!

Comment: why component={Login} will work and render={Login} not? what's the difference? @devserkan

Comment: Because, when you use `render` for `Route` it [waits for a callback function](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) then invokes it. This is how you render your components if you want to use `render`. But, you need to use those components as `<Comp />`. This is not about your situation, just for information. So, when you use as `render={Login}` it tries to invoke your component and you got that error as @ColinRicardo explained in their answer. As you know, your component is actually just a function.

Answer (score 0):

The function itself has no errors. Tried this in another component in a different file. Check for errors elsewhere. What were the other 40 lines in the code?

And what's the version of React?